# User-Defined languages in Notepad++ (NLog)

Tags: notepad++, colors, language, xml

In my current company, `NLog` is heavily used for logging purposes, and Notepad++ is used for flat text editing (like logs).

I would like to add `NLog` as a user-defined "language", in order to modify foreground/background colour of the logs, based on the typical `NLog` keywords `Debug`, `Error`, `Warn`, `Info` and `Fatal`.

I hear you saying "Is that all? Just create the corresponding XML-file and off you go.", but there's a catch:

I have started writing the XML-file, it looks as follows (not tested):

```
<NotepadPlus>
    <UserLang name="NLog" ext="log" udlVersion="2.1">
        <Settings>
            <Global caseIgnored="yes" allowFoldOfComments="no" foldCompact="no" forcePureLC="0" decimalSeparator="0" />
            <Prefix Keywords1="no" Keywords2="no" Keywords3="no" Keywords4="no" Keywords5="no" Keywords6="no" Keywords7="no" Keywords8="no" />
        </Settings>
        <KeywordLists>
            <Keywords name="Debug">| Debug |</Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Info">| Info |</Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Error">| Error |</Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Warn">| Warn |</Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Fatal">| Fatal |</Keywords>
        </KeywordLists>
        <Styles>
            <WordsStyle name="Debug" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" colorStyle="1" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="Info"  fgColor="009100" bgColor="0FFFFF" colorStyle="1" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="Error" fgColor="009100" bgColor="8FFFFF" colorStyle="1" fontStyle="0" nesting="32768" />
            <WordsStyle name="Warn"  fgColor="804000" bgColor="4FFFFF" colorStyle="1" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="Fatal" fgColor="0078B3" bgColor="CFFFFF" colorStyle="1" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        </Styles>
    </UserLang>
</NotepadPlus>
```

... but you might already see the catch: I can alter the colour of a keyword, but that's not what I'm looking for: I want the alter the colour of **the entire line the keyword belongs to**.

Having a look at the `Styler Dialog` feature, it's not very promising:

[image]

There is:

- Changing the font, both name, size, bold, italic, underline
- Changing the colour (both foreground and background) and transparency.

... but this all applies for the simple keyword, not the entire line.

Is there a way to alter the colour of an entire line, containing a keyword, in the language settings in Notepad++?

Thanks in advance

P.s.: I tried to add this question to the Notepad++ community but it has been regarded as spam, by a certain Aksimet.

P.s.2: in the meantime I tried [some plugins](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/nppPluginList/blob/master/doc/plugin_list_x64.md), like "[NppTextViz](https://github.com/KubaDee/NppTextViz)" and "[AnalysePlugin](https://sourceforge.net/projects/analyseplugin)", but those don't serve that purpose.

Comment: You probably need to use regex, rather than keywords. You could try to see if `KeywordLists` takes regex. If it doesn't, the plugin [EnhanceAnyLexer](https://github.com/Ekopalypse/EnhanceAnyLexer) might be a solution.

Comment: @harrymc: you would propose something like `^.* | Debug | .*$` where `^` stands for "beginning of line", `$` stands for "end of line", `.*` stands for "any number of any characters" and let's hope that `|` is not treated as an logical `OR` character like in UNIX `grep -E` command?

Comment: I don't know if `^$` are required if the regex is in greedy mode. Try the simplest regex to test the concept, something like `.*Debug.*`

Comment: @ I managed to get something to work, using that plugin. Just one question: in the entry I've created (`0x00ffff[3, 6] = .*\| Info \|.*`), what does the `[3, 6]` stand for? (I just copied it from the already existing `EnhanceAnyLexerConfig.ini` file.

Comment: The `0x00ffff` is the color in RRGGBB hex format. The brackets part I can't guess.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work without a plug-in, i.e. only with user defined language (UDL) in Notepad++ to highlight logs, I have so far only found a partial solution using **delimiters** with `((EOL))` for my simple Python logs. I'm missing RegEx here.

I assume only one message per line without a line break.

For your use case you still have to adjust from `[DEBUG` to e.g. `| Debug`.

[image]

I have added the resulting UDL.xml here to import it for testing.

```xml
<NotepadPlus>
    <UserLang name="MyLog" ext=".log" udlVersion="2.1">
        <Settings>
            <Global caseIgnored="no" allowFoldOfComments="no" foldCompact="no" forcePureLC="0" decimalSeparator="0" />
            <Prefix Keywords1="no" Keywords2="no" Keywords3="no" Keywords4="no" Keywords5="no" Keywords6="no" Keywords7="no" Keywords8="no" />
        </Settings>
        <KeywordLists>
            <Keywords name="Comments">00# 01 02 03 04</Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Numbers, prefix1"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Numbers, prefix2"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Numbers, extras1"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Numbers, extras2"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Numbers, suffix1"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Numbers, suffix2"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Numbers, range"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Operators1"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Operators2"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Folders in code1, open"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Folders in code1, middle"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Folders in code1, close"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Folders in code2, open"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Folders in code2, middle"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Folders in code2, close"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Folders in comment, open"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Folders in comment, middle"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Folders in comment, close"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Keywords1"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Keywords2"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Keywords3"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Keywords4"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Keywords5"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Keywords6"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Keywords7"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Keywords8"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Delimiters">00[DEBUG 01 02((EOL)) 03[INFO 04 05((EOL)) 06[WARNING 07 08((EOL)) 09[ERROR 10 11((EOL)) 12[CRITICAL 13 14((EOL)) 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23</Keywords>
        </KeywordLists>
        <Styles>
            <WordsStyle name="DEFAULT" fgColor="C0C0C0" bgColor="FFFFFF" colorStyle="1" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="COMMENTS" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="LINE COMMENTS" fgColor="FF8000" bgColor="FFFFFF" colorStyle="1" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="NUMBERS" fgColor="C0C0C0" bgColor="FFFFFF" colorStyle="1" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS1" fgColor="8080FF" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="1" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS2" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS3" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS4" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS5" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS6" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS7" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS8" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="OPERATORS" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="FOLDER IN CODE1" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="FOLDER IN CODE2" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="FOLDER IN COMMENT" fgColor="008000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="3" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS1" fgColor="8080FF" bgColor="FFFFFF" colorStyle="1" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS2" fgColor="0080FF" bgColor="FFFFFF" colorStyle="1" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS3" fgColor="FF8080" bgColor="FFFFFF" colorStyle="1" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS4" fgColor="FF0000" bgColor="FFFFFF" colorStyle="1" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS5" fgColor="FF00FF" bgColor="FFFFFF" colorStyle="1" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS6" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS7" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS8" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        </Styles>
    </UserLang>
</NotepadPlus>
```